# Double passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

> They expected a meeting to be held.

While turning this sentence into passive voice Is it correct to say ;

> A meeting was expected by them to be held .

Is my oppinion correct or should I use different sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A meeting was expected by them to be held.

This is grammatical, but awkward and jarring. It would be much better to express this in a different way. Unless there is a compelling reason to use the passive voice, your first example ("They expected a meeting to be held") is *much* better.